# Can someone help me keep the footer at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I've looked up how to stick the footer to the bottom of the page but i'm having trouble making it actually work! If i post my code can you look at it and change it to make it work, but also explain how you did it?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Aaron Kelsey - Home</title>`enter code here`

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header_wrapper">

            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
            <div id="line-1"></div>
            <div id="line-2"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <img class="header" src="images/header.png">


        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

img.header{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.header_wrapper{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    padding:10px;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:150px;
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;  
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#line-1{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    top: 10px;
}

#line-2{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    top: 50px;
}

#navigation {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 50px; 
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A9A9A9;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #1e1e1e;
}
```

Comment: I just cut/pasted your code into an html file and loaded it into IE. Seems to work fine. I put ABC in the footer and it appeared at the bottom of the page with a gray background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your footer inside of the wrapper. It is fixed at the bottom of that div but not the body.

take the footer div outside of your wrapper and it is good to go.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header_wrapper">
      <ul id="navigation">
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="line-1"></div>
  <div id="line-2"></div>
  <div class="content">
      <img class="header" src="images/header.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/mVXkH/)

Also in your footer you don't need to have `margin: 0 auto;` since it is 100%. The next thing is close your image tags like so, `<img src="" alt="" />`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've only just start my college course for web development so just trying to get to grips with it.